# Don't pass the data from nova select field

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I have a nova select field that is meant to toggle another field but not to pass the data to the model, how do I make it silent, so that it doesn't try to fill a model field.

It should be through the fillUsing() method, but I'm not getting it right, any help?

Here is my code

```
lect::make('Place')->options([
                1 => 1
                2 => 2
                3 => 3
            ])
 BelongsTo::make('Event Place', 'eventPlacePublic')
    ->dependsOn('place', function (Field $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
                    if (!in_array($formData['place'],[1,2])) {
                        $field->hide();
                        $field->rules('sometimes');
                    }
                }),
```

Because I don't have a db column called place, I cannot have the place field passed along with all other.

fillUsing() should provide a way to modify the fields attribute on hydration but I can't figure out how to hide the filed altogether via the fillUsing method